# Pylinting a python 2 fallback

Tags: python, pylint

I have a python module with a python 2 fallback set up through try/catch.

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    from urlib import urlencode
```

When I pylint the file I get *no name 'urlencode' in module 'urllib'* and similar errors. Is there anyway to specify python 2 linting for a block, disable all linting for a block, or am I stuck hand squelching all errors?

Comment: You can use an inline comment on the line corresponding to the version you *aren't* running `pylint` with (`# pylint: disable=rule-name`).

Comment: This is what I am doing now, but I was hoping I had missed something cleaner and faster. Something as simple as 'disable all linting over the following block' would save me time and make my code more readable.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can do it at line or block level (although in this case the block would presumably be your whole module) - see http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#message-control

Answer (score 0):

I settled on a nicer way of doing this by disabling the linting errors at the beginning of a python 2 block, and then re enabling them at the end.

```
# pylint: disable=no-name-in-module, import-error
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen
# pylint: enable=no-name-in-module, import-error
```